# Why go package unsafe source code only six lines?

Tags: go

```
package unsafe
type ArbitraryType int
type Pointer *ArbitraryType
func Sizeof(x ArbitraryType) uintptr
func Offsetof(x ArbitraryType) uintptr
func Alignof(x ArbitraryType) uintptr
```

What's the principle of Sizeof, Offsetof, Alignof?

Comment: The [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/) explains the usage for those. What additional information do you need about them?

Answer (score 2):

Usually just having a function signature without an implementations means that the implementation is elsewhere. Usually in a separate assembly file.

In this case, you have stumbled upon one of two situations in the standard library where it is not implemented in assembly: [unsafe](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/) and [builtin](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/).

The Go implementation of those packages are only there to provide documentation inside godoc. Their use is defined in the [Go language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec) and because of that are implemented in a way that would be impossible to implement in Go. In the case of unsafe, "ArbitraryType" really means that it accepts all possible types. This would normally be impossible to do without implicit interface conversion. But the functions are implemented by the compiler as they are needed and get to ignore the normal restrictions on Go code.

---

But what is the unsafe package? It is a package that provides various tools for doing low level work. Its main use is in doing direct syscalls or cgo. Using unsafe gives you a great amount of power but also doesn't stop you from using that power to shoot yourself in the foot. If at all possible, I recommend avoiding it.

---

Further reading:

- https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/
- https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_unsafe